# JavaScript Explanation of brackets

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain me which bracket here is used for what?

```
let myModule = (function() {})();
```

i know that the inner part = function() { // Some stuff here } is a function, so what does

```
(innerpart)();
```

?
How and why is it different from

```
let myModule = function() {}
```

Comment: Google IIFE. That's what we call it

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

Comment: (innerpart)(); is used for self invokable function.

Comment: Wow Thank you very much, that was fast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you declare do:

```
let foo = function () {}
```

you're just declaring a function foo

when you do:

```
let foo = (function() {})();
```

edited: thanks to @VLAZ

you're declaring a function foo and calling it right away. It's the same as:

```
let f = function() {} 
let foo = f()
```

Comment: That last part is not quite correct. That must be `foo = foo()` to be equivalent.

Comment: It's not. `foo` will be a completely different thing in those two cases.

Comment: More like `f = function() {}` followed by `foo = f()` because you are getting the result of that execution. Also, you are throwing away `f` afterwards.